# End of for loop options in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

What else can I do at the end other than printing this out to a file?  I don't know any other way to end a for loop and I don't want to have unnecessary files all over the place.  As an example:

```
data = open(filename, "r")
found = open("Found.txt", "w")

for line in data:
    if re.match("(.*)(background-color:red)(.*)", line):
        print >> found, line,
```

I don't WANT to save `found` at the end...but I don't know how else to take the matched data and do anything with it.  I've been beating my face on the desk for hours, searched all over the place and I have no idea.  Seems so basic...lol

Please help...

Comment: Please read a Python book (or at least post intelligible questions).

Comment: if its in a function just `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `break` to exit from a loop. And why do you need an output file? (by the way: that's *not* the correct way to write to a file). Just print the line, if that's what you intend:

```
for line in data:
    if re.match("(.*)(background-color:red)(.*)", line):
        print line
        break
```

Or save the line in a variable, for using it later. This really depends on what your program is supposed to do, and whether the results of the match need to be persisted for future reference, or if it's enough to save them in-memory for further processing:

```
result = None

for line in data:
    if re.match("(.*)(background-color:red)(.*)", line):
        result = line
        break

if result:
    # do something with `result`
    pass
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this answers the question? I don't really know what the question is.

Comment: Difficult thing to explain.  This helped.  Thank you.